# Is it possible to assign GitHub issues directly to project boards when creating the issue in Visual Studio Code using GitHub pull requests and issues?

Tags: visual-studio-code, github-actions

Environment:

- VSCode installed
- Signed in to GitHub in VSCode
- "GitHub pull requests and issues" extension installed
- Single repository open that has known project boards, eg. "**General**"

Explanation:
If I open the Command Palette in VSCode and type "GitHub Issues: Create an issue" and press enter, a file opens. The file is called "NewIssue.md" and contains the following:

```
Issue Title

Assignees: Comma-separated usernames, either @username or just username.
Labels: Comma-separated labels.


<!-- Edit the body of your new issue then click the ✓ "Create Issue" button in the top right of
the editor. The first line will be the issue title. Assignees and Labels follow after a blank
line. Leave an empty line before beginning the body of the issue. -->
```

I am able to create an issue and body with a title as suggested in the comment block.

**Is there a way to assign this to a project board within this file?**
*I have tried adding `Projects: General` below `Labels:`*
It created the issue but did not automatically assign it to the project board.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the beta project board, you can use this action: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/add-to-github-projects-beta to add issues to your board from a workflow.

The action is pretty well documented but the overall idea is you have a workflow that is triggered on new issues or changes to existing issue labels and if the labels match a list that you define, then the issue is added to the board.

Comment: Sorry, unbeknown to me I have been signed out of SO for a very long time and did not see your answer. Unfortunately, the link provided takes me to a 404 page now. I will have a look further into this when I have the time and try to reply with more findings.